# How to override class files (asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass)?

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

```
What I am trying to do?
```

I am trying to add try/catch block in start and end of a particular method.

```
Why am I overriding asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(String class1,String class2)?
```

I am using flag COMPUTE_FRAMES, and because of that, asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass() this class is being called and it is trying to load some classes again using class.ForName(), and saying classNotFoundException. I read somewhere to override this method and make sure it gets these two classes loaded. I got hold of Instrumentation object and got all loaded classes, but there are still some classes which are not loaded and this method throws NullPointer Exception..

```
Any suggesstions how to override it?
```

**EDITED THE QUESTION BASED ON BELOW RESPONSE**

**What I understand here is :**

**1. There is no need to use COMPUTE_FRAMES instead of COMPUTE_MAXS, if I am trying to add a try/catch block for method content.**

**2. If I want to just add try/catch block for method content,(assume jdk8 only) then i just need to write try/catch block ASM part and rest should fall in place.**

For a method which is called from a thread:

```
public void execute()throws IOException{
//some code

}
```

Below code should add try/catch block and should not give  any java verify error?:

```
private Label startFinally = new Label();
  public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
       Label endFinally = new Label();
       visitTryCatchBlock(startFinally, endFinally, endFinally, "java/lang/Exception");
       visitLabel(endFinally);
       visitFrame(F_NEW, 0, null, 1, new Object[]{"java/lang/Exception"});
       visitVarInsn(ASTORE, 1);
       visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
       visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Exception", "printStackTrace", "()V", false);
       visitInsn(RETURN);
}

  public void visitCode() {     

        mv.visitLabel(startFinally);  
        super.visitCode();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you assume that these classes are already loaded? It’s not unusual that a class has not been loaded yet.

Answer (score 7):

When you start having to deal with `getCommonSuperClass` you are entering the very issue that stack map frames were designed to solve. Instead of letting the verifier do such a common superclass search, the frames derived from information available to the compiler should tell which type to assume and verifying the correctness is cheaper than performing this search.

But, of course, if you use a framework like ASM and let it conveniently calculate all these frames from scratch without the information available to the compiler, you end up doing that expensive operation and even have to assist ASM in case the types are not available to a simple `Class.forName` call (or you want avoid the loading of the classes).

You should note two important things:

- You don’t have to load these classes. This method intentionally provides two strings and expect a result string. If you have meta information available that allow you to determine the common super type based on the name, you can use it
- When you use Instrumentation to search for the name among all loaded classes, you might miss the class because it might not have been loaded yet. Even worse, you could get the wrong class in a more complex scenario when classes with the same name have been loaded by different `ClassLoader`s

---

At this time you should think about whether adhering to the original intent of using the already known information to generate the right frame is an option. When you instrument a class of a version where stack map frames are mandatory, all frames beside the one required for your exception handler are already present. And for older class files without frames, you don’t need to compute them anyway.

When you chain a `ClassReader` with a `ClassWriter` it will not only replicate members and instructions but also the stack map frames, unless you specify `COMPUTE_FRAMES` which causes ASM to drop all visited frames and recalculate them from scratch. So the first thing to do is to change `COMPUTE_FRAMES` back to `COMPUTE_MAXS` and then insert `visitFrame` calls as needed.

For covering the entire method with one exception handler, we need exactly one frame, for the entry of the handler (assuming there are no branches inside the handler itself). We already know that the operand stack consist of a sole reference to the exception itself—that’s always the case for exception handlers. Since the guarded code spans the entire method, no additional local variables introduced inside the method are available, so only `this` (if the method is not `static`) and the parameters are available—unless the method’s code reuses them for other purposes (ordinary Java code usually doesn’t). But the good news is, you don’t have to deal with them unless you want to use them.

So let’s assume we want to cover the entire method with an exception handler which will catch the exception, print its stack trace and return (assuming `void`). Then, we don’t need any local variables and the entire code, applied after completely visiting the original code, looks like:

```
Label endFinally = new Label();
visitTryCatchBlock(startFinally, endFinally, endFinally, "java/lang/Exception");
visitLabel(endFinally);
visitFrame(F_NEW, 0, null, 1, new Object[]{"java/lang/Exception"});
visitVarInsn(ASTORE, 1);
visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Exception", "printStackTrace", "()V", false);
visitInsn(RETURN);
```

The logic is

```
visitFrame(F_NEW,                          // not derived from a previous frame
    0, null,                               // no local variables
    1, new Object[]{"java/lang/Exception"} // one exception on the stack
);
```

Of course, the type of the exception on the stack must match the type of the `visitTryCatchBlock` or be a super type of it. Note that the local variable we’re going to introduce *after* entering the handler is irrelevant. If you want to re-throw instead of returning, just replace

```
visitInsn(RETURN);
```

with

```
visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
visitInsn(ATHROW);
```

and the logic regarding the stack map frame doesn’t change.

Comment: Yes, I understood these two points but was just confirming about that verify error when I execute the code. And May be i am getting the verify erro because I am not calling super.visitMax(). Here is the error :Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/asm/ASM1.printTwo(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V @3: ldc
  Reason:
    Exceeded max stack size.

Comment: That might be due to the missing `super.visitMaxs`. The next time you have a question about an exception or error, include that exception/error in your question…